# Per Pixel Collision for two LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9?

Tags: c++, directx

I have searched and haven't found anything related to C++ code and DX `LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9`, all i can find is per pixel collisions for other engines, i need something native , now i have a bounding box collisions which works as expected, but as you know when the collision happens between two alpha pixels it will also report it as true, so i need to enhance it and make it per pixel.

So currently i have two Rects and two `LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9`, with intersectRect function i can know if there is a collision, then i need go further by dealing with lockRect and pbits but seems i cannot figure it out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, i solve it, its the same way i described, lockrect and loop over pbits.